# Как изменить цвет линии в TabWidget Android?

Tags: android

Всем привет. Есть три вкладки:

```
<TabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/tabHost">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:background="#008cd8"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/artist_tab"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">



                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/album_tab"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                    android:orientation="vertical">


                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/song_tab"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ListView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/listView" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

Выглядит это вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно изменить цвет выделенной вкладки? сейчас если присмотреть то он синий, хочу изменить на другой, что бы было более читабельно!

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы изменить цвет прийдеться создать новую графику с нужным цветом. Далее ее установить.

1. Создать 2 xml файла

left_strip.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_press_bar_left"/>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_bar_left"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus_bar_left"/>
```

right_strip.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_press_bar_right"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_bar_right"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus_bar_right"/>
</selector>
```

2. В коде у `TabWidget` вызвать 2 метода `setLeftStripDrawable` и `setRightStripDrawable` или в xml `android:tabStripLeft` и `android:tabStripRight`

Рекомендую посмотреть в сторону [PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html)